# How to 'name' images in Rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So in html you can have the code `<img class="myimage" src="image.jpg">` which makes editing in `.css` easier.
What is the equivalent of this when working with a `.html.erb` file?

e.g where do I define the class in this `<%= image_tag "image.jpg" %>`?

Comment: I assume you mean you're using Rails, not just Ruby? They're not the same thing. Rails is the web application framework written in Ruby. If you look at the Rails documentation for `image_tag` you'll find what you need. Just Google "rails image_tag" and you'll find it. What version of Rails are you using? Using the older style hash, you can do: `<%= image_tag 'image.jpg', :class => 'myimage' %>`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm only new, yes I it is Rails. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use the native HTML in a .html.erb file, exactly as you've shown.  This definitely works in the ERB template:

```
<img class="myimage" src="image.jpg">
```

This will often render slightly faster than using a dynamic approach, and has the benefit of being exactly what you intend.

If you choose the dynamic tag option, you can refer to the [ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) reference.  To get the Rails (ActionView) equivalent to what you've shown, you can use this syntax:

```
<%= image_tag 'image.jpg', class: 'myimage' %>
```

Note that the portion with the `class: 'myimage'` is providing the `class` attribute as a hash value, and this is simply shortcut syntax for `{ class: 'myimage' }`.

You can also provide an ID to distinguish this image from other images of the same class by providing the `id` option, like so:

```
<%= image_tag 'image.jpg', class: 'myimage', id: 'image-1' %>
```

This will generate the following HTML:

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="myimage" id="image-1">
```

From that point, you can style the `image-1` image independently of other `myimage` images, should you need to do so.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this syntax;

```
<%= image_tag('foo.jpg', class: 'myimage') %>
```

it will work for you!

Answer (score 1):

I think comma will help, so:

```
 <%= image_tag 'foo.jpg', class: 'bar' %>
```